# Session or Cookies? most use

Tags: c#, session, cookies

I want to store some data to use it in next page then i'll insert it to database like

```
Trip.TripID
Trip.BookingDate
Trip.Adult
Trip.Chile
```

and count how many trips 
what is the object used for this

Comment: SESSION!...Cookies could be disabled, plus, in the EU are under new legislation, in which you must ask your target audience if they want to allow their usage.

Comment: COOKIES! Session isn't preserved over a recycle nor does it scale well to multiple servers. I think this might get religious. Voting to close.

Comment: How are you moving to the next page? You could always persist data in post parameters/query string on the page and not use either cookies or session.

Comment: how can i use session for this example i can create 1 session but with 1 Value i want to save more than one value in one session name.

Comment: @AhmedSharkawy, you can store your Trip object to the session and retrieve it back, You don't need to store each value separately in the session

Answer (score 1):

If its a small size object then you can store it the session. Only thing for which you should be concerned about it is that Sessions are maintained on the server side.

You can store the object in the seesion like.

```
Session["TripObject"] = TripObject;
```

and to retrieve it back.

```
Trip sessionTripObject = (Trip) Session["TripObject"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Session has bitten me more than once.

IMO client state does not belong on the server, other than in the DB (especially if you need to scale out to more than a single server, in which case session will fail and you'll need to back it off with a database/session server anyway).

Seeing as you're almost definitely using cookies already to keep your users logged in, you could easily store another.

Answer (score 0):

your decision between session and cookies involves many things, but for small pieces of data that are only needed between pages in a 'single session' is better to use sessions.

if you want persistent general data is better if you are using cookies, be aware though, that you should always consider the psosbility of losing data in cookies

Answer (score 0):

Store short time values in session is a waste of server memory. You can release it when retrieve in the second page but ¿what happens if the user close the browser? The values are wasting memory until session timeout which can be about 30 mins in a common scenario.

As activwerx says Cookies could be disable and must be encripted if the data is dangerous.

Use a public property in first Page with the trip list, redirect and retrieve the trip list using Page.PreviousPage.

Basic code:

To get public property values from the source page
On the source page, create one or more public properties and save the page.

```
Public ReadOnly Property CurrentCity() As String
    Get
        Return textCity.Text
    End Get
End Property
public String CurrentCity
{
    get
    {
        return textCity.Text;
    }
}
```

Note
Properties on the source page that are created primarily to expose values for cross-page posting are usually read-only properties. Although the source page can contain public read/write properties, setting a source page property from the target page property generally has no purpose, because the value will not be persisted.

On the target page, add a `@ PreviousPageType` page directive that points to the source page.

The following code example shows a PreviousPageType directive that references a source page named SourcePage.aspx

```
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
```

The PreviousPageType directive causes the page's PreviousPage property to be typed to the source page class.

In target page code, use strongly typed members of the PreviousPage property to read the source code properties.

```
Label1.Text = PreviousPage.CurrentCity;
```

Works with a post to the TargetPage

SourcePage.aspx

```
<asp:Button 
  ID="Button1" 
  PostBackUrl="~/TargetPage.aspx"
  runat="server"
  Text="Submit" />
```

And `Server.Transfer(targetPage)`